# Optional.orElse: how to continue the stream?

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I would like to use the Stream approach, but I feel that it is somewhat sub-optimal. I would like to avoid the confusing

```
.map(Optional::of)
```

Is it possible to make the method #2 below to avoid this extra confusion, is there a optional method I could use to achieve what I want?

```
// Either map can be null, empty, or have the value for key
Map<String,String> map1 =  
Map<String,String> map2 = 


// Method #1
String value1 = null;
if (map1 != null) {
   value1 = map1.get(key);
}

if (value1 == null) {
   if (map2 != null) {
      value1 = map2.get(key);
   }
}

if (value1 == null) value1 = "default";

// Method #2
String value2 = Optional.ofNullable(map1)
    .map(map -> map.get(key))
    .map(Optional::of)
    .orElse(Optional.ofNullable(map2).map(map -> map.get(key)))
    .orElse("default");


assertEquals(value1, value2);
```

I would like to have something like this:

```
Optional.ofNullable(map1)
    .map(map -> map.get(key))
    .orOptional(Optional.ofNullable(map2).map(map -> map.get(key)))
    .orElse("default");
```

Where orOptional would be something like:
     // If a value is present in this Optional return this optional, otherwise return fallback
      Optional orOptional(Optional fallback)

Edit 2018-10-15: To not get stuck on the fact that I used maps in the example, lets assume those are just some beans with getter for a value. Either bean can be null or the values returned by getters can be null.

Comment: If I understand your need correctly - there are two methods like these `orElse` and `orElseGet`.

Comment: in Java 9, there is a method: 'or': https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-

Comment: @user_3380739, exactly what I wanted! Too bad I am on 8.

Comment: “*Either map can be null, empty, or have the value for key*” **That’s** the problem. Don’t let the maps be `null` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

you don't need

```
.map(map -> map.get(key))
        .map(Optional::of)
```

`Optional.map` also returns `Optional`. you can just write

```
Optional.ofNullable(map1)
                .map(map -> map.get(key))
                .orElseGet(() ->
                        Optional.ofNullable(map2)
                                .map(map -> map.get(key)).orElse("default")
                );
```

Also, you can create a stream of maps and then do some tranformations:

```
Stream.of(map1, map2)
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .map(m -> m.get(key))
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .findFirst()
  .orElse("default");
```

Comment: Don't you need a second `.filter(m -> m != null)` (or `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` between the .map and the .findfirst? Otherwise if `m.get(key)` returns null, `findfirst` will throw an NPE.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException you are definitely right. I updated my answer.

Comment: @dehasi, I actually prefer my original way better, as it has the orElse("Default") on the top level (not nested inside another Optional mapping). For reader it is clear that no matter what happens in nested Optionals, there is default fallback value.

You second solution of stream of maps. Does it quarantee that findFirst() is from the map1 if present? I dont think so.

Comment: According to JavaDoc `Stream.of(...)` returns `Returns a sequential {@link Stream}`.  Doesn't it guarantee that findFirst() will be from the map1?

Comment: In the fist solution you could replace `orElse(...)` by `orElseGet(...)` to avoid creating and evaluating the second `Optional` any time.

Comment: @LuCio I'm not sure that I understand your point, `orElse(...)` takes a value but  `orElseGet(...)` takes a supplier. Both of them return a value, not an optional.

Comment: `orElseGet(Supplier supplier)` will execute the `supplier` only in the else-case. So if the `Optional` will have a not-null state after the first `map` the `supplier` will not be executed and thus the second `Optional` will not be created and evaluated. Using `orElse(T other)` will create and evaluate the second `Optional` any time to determine the else value - even if it is not going to be used.

Comment: Looks like I understood. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental design error in letting the map variables ever become `null`.

If you can’t fix the source of the maps, you should at least introduce local variables holding non-`null` maps as early as possible in your processing.

```
Map<String,String> m1 = map1 == null? Map.of(): map1, m2 = map2 == null? Map.of(): map2;
```

`Map.of()` requires Java 9. In Java 8, you can use `Collections.emptyMap()` instead.

Then, your task is as easy as

```
String value1 = m1.getOrDefault(key, m2.getOrDefault(key, "default"));
```

Comment: You are right, but lets make the question a bit more generic, by replacing the maps with some arbitrary objects with some getters. And assume either of the objects can be null or the getter returned value can be null.